# How to set up a compute engine instance with GPU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up an instance with GPU NVIDIA K80 but have an error: "you are out of your NVIDIA K80 quota". What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

First, please keep in mind that free trial accounts do not receive GPU quota by default.

Then, you can either request a quota increase for your account on the [compute quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) page or you might be able to get more GPU machines in [other zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/).